# Error while allocating tensors in tflite Interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am making a Linear Regression model (3 input parameters of type float) that can be made to run on-device in an Android app that makes predictions based on user input.
For this, I have used the TensorFlow estimator tf.estimator.LinearRegressor. I also made a SavedModel out of this using this code:

```py
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec([crim, indus, tax]))
export_path = model_est.export_saved_model("saved_model", serving_input_fn)
```

where the feature columns have been defined before in the code as:

```py
tax = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('tax')
indus = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('indus')
crim = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('crim')
```

The whole model building code is as follows:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
TRAIN_CSV_PATH = './data/BostonHousing_subset.csv'
TEST_CSV_PATH = './data/boston_test_subset.csv'
PREDICT_CSV_PATH = './data/boston_predict_subset.csv'

# target variable to predict:
LABEL_PR = "medv"

def get_batch(file_path, batch_size, num_epochs=None, **args):
    with open(file_path) as file:
        num_rows = len(file.readlines())

    dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
        file_path, batch_size, label_name=LABEL_PR, num_epochs=num_epochs, header=True, **args)

    # repeat and shuffle and batch separately instead of the previous line
    # for clarity purposes
    # dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
    # dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    elem = iterator.get_next()
    return elem


# Now to define the feature columns
tax = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('tax')
indus = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('indus')
crim = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('crim')

# Building the model
model_est = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=[crim, indus, tax], model_dir='model_dir')

# Train it now
model_est.train(steps=2300, input_fn=lambda: get_batch(TRAIN_CSV_PATH, batch_size=256))

results = model_est.evaluate(steps=1000, input_fn=lambda: get_batch(TEST_CSV_PATH, batch_size=128))

for key in results:
    print("   {}, was: {}".format(key, results[key]))

to_pred = {
    'crim': [0.03359, 5.09017, 0.12650, 0.05515, 8.15174, 0.24522],
    'indus': [2.95, 18.10, 5.13, 2.18, 18.10, 9.90],
    'tax': [252, 666, 284, 222, 666, 304],
}


def test_get_inp():
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(to_pred)
    return dataset

# Predict
for pred_results in model_est.predict(input_fn=test_get_inp):
    print(pred_results['predictions'][0])

# Now to export as SavedModel
print(tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec([crim, indus, tax]))
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec([crim, indus, tax]))

export_path = model_est.export_saved_model("saved_model", serving_input_fn)
```

The code I am using to convert this SavedModel to tflite format is:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('saved_model/1576168761')
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]

tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

which outputs a .tflite file.

However, when I try to load this tflite file using this code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="converted_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Documents/Projects/boston_house_pricing/get_model_details.py", line 5, in <module>
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\boston_housing\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\lite\python\interpreter.py", line 244, in allocate_tensors
    return self._interpreter.AllocateTensors()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\boston_housing\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\lite\python\interpreter_wrapper\tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper.py", line 106, in AllocateTensors
    return _tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper.InterpreterWrapper_AllocateTensors(self)
RuntimeError: Regular TensorFlow ops are not supported by this interpreter. Make sure you invoke the Flex delegate before inference.Node number 0 (FlexParseExample) failed to prepare.
```

I am unable to understand how to resolve this error. Also, an error with the same message is thrown when I try to initialize an interpreter with this file (Android) in Java using tflite.

Help would be greatly appreciated regarding the same.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the error explains the issue pretty well, when converting to tflite you have specified the tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS flag, which causes the converter to include operations that are not supported by tflite natively, and it expects that you will use the flex module in tflite to compile and include those operations in the interpreter.
For more info regarding flex: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select

In any case you have two main options, either use flex and compile the needed ops, or to use only operations that are supported natively by tflite and omit the tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS flag.

For natively supported tensorflow ops refer here: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_compatibility

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more? I use the tflite_runtime on a raspberry Pi and I try to use a converted model (conversion in Python like this exampe: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select). What should I do for this: "it expects that you will use the flex module in tflite to compile and include those operations in the interpreter"?
If I omit the tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS flag in the conversion I get conversion errors like "op is a TFLite builtin op but builtin emission is not enabled". With the flag tflite complains: "apply/link the Flex delegate ... (FlexStridedSlice)"

Comment: I figured it out: to create the model (before converting it to Tensorflow Lite) I had to use "export_tflite_graph_tf2.py". I could convert that output to Tensorflow Lite omitting the tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS flag.